# c# Convert LINQ var result to actual type

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In c#, Given the following code:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    for (int i = 0; i != 15; i++)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.PersonID = i;
        p.Age = i * 12;
        p.Name = "Name " + i;
        people.Add(p);
    }


    var sortedPeople = from qPeople in people
                       where qPeople.Age > 0 && qPeople.Age < 25 || qPeople.Age > 100
                       orderby qPeople.Age descending
                       select qPeople;
```

Can I load the results of sortedPeople back into a List<Person> without a loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, instead of `for (int i = 0; i != 15; i++)`, use `for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)` - some funny and mysterious infinite loops can come up if `i` is ever modified inside the block

Comment: If you don't understand that var is a compiler-inferred type declaration, then you shouldn't use var.

Comment: @James Kolpack: Infinite loops are at least easy to discover. I suppose some mysterious unexpected behavior can come up if you use `i < 15` and discovering that may be more difficult (the point is - modifying `i` inside the block is a road to hell anyway).

Comment: @Tomas Petricek - agreed, modifying looping index is (usually) bad news.  In this case I'd rather see `foreach (var i in Enumberable.Range(1,15)) { ... }` (or work the object instantiation into the LINQ expression) to minimize the potential for this kind of problem.  Aside - I'm reading (and enjoying) your Real-World Functional Programming book, two thumbs up.

Comment: @James Kolpack: Using `Range` method is an interesting way to avoid the problem. I'm glad you're enjoying the book, thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. There is a .ToList() extension method available, so all you would need to do is make a call to it like this.

```
var sortedPeople = (from qPeople in people 
                       where qPeople.Age > 0 && qPeople.Age < 25 || qPeople.Age > 100 
                       orderby qPeople.Age descending 
                       select qPeople).ToList();
```

Now sortedPeople will be a `List<Person>` instead of an `IOrderedEnumerable<Person>`

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
sortedPeople.ToList()
```

[Enumerable.ToList Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)

> Creates a List from an
>   IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var sortedPeople = (from qPeople in people
                       where qPeople.Age > 0 && qPeople.Age < 25 || qPeople.Age > 100
                       orderby qPeople.Age descending
                       select qPeople).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<Person> sortedPeople = from...
```

Fixed!

Also:

```
List<Person> personList = sortedPeople.ToList();
```

Note, the `ToList` method loops over the results to produce this list.